# Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, java-11

I'm new to selenium webdriver and java programming. Trying to resolve the error in eclipse 2018-12 "The import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver cannot be resolved" Im using java 11, selenium standalone server 3.141.59 . Kindly help. I'm unable to import jar files Below is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: What steps did you take to add that JAR to your project? Do you have it added to your build path?

Comment: I added the jars by right clicking name of the project-build path-configure build path and then i added all external jars under the modulepath. I also tried to add all jars under classpath but that also didn't work. I just edited my question with the screenshot of the build path too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Can't compile Java9 module with selenium-java as dependency](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5896) it seems the *Selenium* packages can't be compiled with **Java 9** due to **split packages** and till *May 15, 2018* Selenium wasn't fully compatible with Java 9.

But as per this [comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6100#issuecomment-402977443) @Jarob22 mentioned, Selenium works just fine using **Java 10**. **Java 9** is already eol and there's not much point adding extra stuff to try and support just it if 10 works.

But with the landing of [e57914a](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/e57914ab0550e7b755bfd664d61040ae7856b03d) Simon introduced us with **basic JPMS support**. With this availability [(mhomnag/selenium-java10-reproducer@bc63889)](https://github.com/mhomnag/selenium-java10-reproducer/commit/bc638891395ca28ef5ae4fc5ecb330991c95a79b) now actually builds but you may have to [Remove the WebDriverWaiter and just use a sleep for now](https://github.com/mhomnag/selenium-java10-reproducer/commit/72f3be2642f2aac82dc3c8ac9398b0d99f07858e).

---

### Java 11

As you are using **java.version: '11.0.1'**, *selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar* is still not compatible with **Java 11**. But once **Java 11** ships and **Buck** supports it the toolchain witll be rejiged to support *Java 11*.

---

### Solution

The strategic solution will be to install the latest version of [**JDK 8u212**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and execute the *@Tests*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got your point. i fixed all my import errors by using selenium-standalone-server-v2.7 and jar files v 3.52. Thankyou! It would be great if you can help me in another query, I downloaded eclipse neon 3 initially, but i got log error while launching. I tried other eclipse versions too like oxygen, mars etc, nothing worked. Can you help me out. Thankyou

Comment: @reyrro Your other query seems to be all together a new question. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stack Overflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Yes sure.Thanks.