# Protractor Update breaking E2E tests

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm trying to update the protractor module on an Angular application. It's a large leap in versions, from 2.4.0 to the current 5.4.2. As you might imagine, this is causing the e2e tests on the application to break. Right now I'm getting this error:

```
[13:29:13] E/launcher - Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "count": 1,
    "browserName": "phantomjs",
    "phantomjs.binary.path": "\u002fusr\u002flocal\u002fbin\u002fphantomjs"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "phantomjs"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'ITSPAREMAC1.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4a7:164:5eb8:f7ed%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[13:29:13] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "count": 1,
    "browserName": "phantomjs",
    "phantomjs.binary.path": "\u002fusr\u002flocal\u002fbin\u002fphantomjs"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "phantomjs"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'ITSPAREMAC1.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4a7:164:5eb8:f7ed%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I have already tried `webdriver-manager clean -> webdriver-manager update`. I've also reinstalled the other npm packages on the app. Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228) helps you?

Comment: @DebanjanB It does not. Same error, different java version.

Comment: Can you share your protractor.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your config

```
  directConnect: true,
```

Note: remove `seleniumAddress` from your config if you use `directConnect`.

To update webdriver go to your project folder and run `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`