# Does anyone know if Selenium and Appium accept Java version 12?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am currently using java version 8 for selenium and appium. Does it work with java 12 or which is the highest I can go ?

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228) helps you?

Comment: why not? I used java 11 to write tests using appium and to be honest I don't see why it wouldn't work with 12

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB and olyv