# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService with Selenium 3.14.0 and Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-remotedriver

Python 3.7.3

Pycharm 2019.1.3

selenium standalone 3.14.0

Selenium 3.141.0

Java JDK 12.0.2

Windows 7

When I try to run script using remote webdriver a got the error, my 
java.version is not what I expected (expected version at least 12.):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'host_name', ip: 'localhost', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.lambda$get$0 (ServicedSession.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.apply (ServicedSession.java:151)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$12 (ActiveSessionFactory.java:177)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.apply (ActiveSessionFactory.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$2 (NewSessionPipeline.java:65)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$3 (NewSessionPipeline.java:68)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.tryAdvance (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (None:-1)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession (NewSessionPipeline.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute (BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$3 (WebDriverServlet.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (None:-1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)
```

I've tried to reinstall java JDK but version stay the same as was - 1.8.0_221

My code in python:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://10.20.10.193:4444/wd/hub',
   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)

driver.get('https://google.com')
```

set selenium server:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have  node registered on hub? Also version of Chrome & chrome driver .Are they compatible ?

Comment: no i don't have node registered on hub - gonna try it. Yes Chrome and chrome driver version ale compatible v76.

Comment: http://allselenium.info/execute-python-selenium-tests-in-selenium-grid/ Check tutorial.  Without  node test will  not run.

Comment: still something wrong, but i will get it from now, thank you good man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'host_name', ip: 'localhost', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** is not getting recognized.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

[Selenium Client Driver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/) page mentions:

- Supported Python Versions:

  ```
    Python 2.7, 3.4+
  ```
- But the list on [selenium 3.141.0](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) page includes only:
- [Python :: 2.7](https://pypi.org/search/?c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python+%3A%3A+2.7)
- [Python :: 3.4](https://pypi.org/search/?c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python+%3A%3A+3.4)
- [Python :: 3.5](https://pypi.org/search/?c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python+%3A%3A+3.5)
- [Python :: 3.6](https://pypi.org/search/?c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python+%3A%3A+3.6)

So possibly **Python 3.7.3** is still not supported and you may have to downgrade python to a relevant version.

---

### Outro

[Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228)

Comment: Where on that page are you reading that only 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 are supported?

Comment: @DebanjanB i was running python 3.8, so i downgraded to 3.6.3, but still the same error.