# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException executing Selenium tests using TestNG and Java 12 through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng, testng-eclipse, java-12

[ErrorOccuredDuringInitializationofbootlayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNbsT.png) I keep getting this error when I run
 my test:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for
>   C:\Users\Bonfire.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.12.0_867647348_win32_win32_x86_64\plugins\com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   com.beust.jcommander.1.72.0: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java
>   identifier

How can I fix it?

Comment: please post your code, not picture

Comment: Related to [Unable to derive module descriptor for auto generated module names in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9)

Answer (score 8):

Add TestNG Library to classpath in buildpath ( not to module path). It will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid this error, do not add TestNG library in the project or src folder. Try adding it into the package. To do so , follow the below mentioned procedure.

Right click on the package, click Build Path->Configure Build Path, go to Libraries tab, select Classpath and click on Add Library to select TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: 
Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\Bonfire.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.12.0_867647348_win32_win32_x86_64\plugins\com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.beust.jcommander.1.72.0: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java identifier
```

...implies that there was an issue with the **java classpath**.

As per the discussion [Launch with java 11 fails: Error: Could not find or load main class with Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: with](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543562) there are some issues with some particular classpaths for [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) and the launch fails if:

- The classpath contains a *folder with spaces*
- The *classpath length is larger than 32767 characters*.

Where as [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) works fine.

---

### Reference

[Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228)

---

### Outro

[Eclipse plugin: TestNG testcase does not run with Jdk11](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1998)

Comment: I'm not using java 11 I'm using java 12, I've tried installing Java-8 but has error on compatibility

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to add 1.8 version library
2. Remove TestNG from build path library and add again
3. Recheck - the issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue and I solved it. When creating the project, don't create `module-info.java`. When the project was already created with the `module-info.java`, deleting this file didn't help me.

I just created new project without `module-info.java`, and all works good now.

Answer (score 0):

Best option to resolve this:

1. Find all file and folder starting with . e.g. — .metadata / .setting and delete them.
2. Add all the JARS.
3. Add `testNG` Libraries.
4. Execute it.

Done.