# Automating Span with Selenium and Java 13

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, java-13

I am automating a website using selenium in Java.

```
<a id="pd-vote-button10359300" class="css-vote-button pds-vote-button"><span>Vote</span></a>
```

For this button I need to automate a Click in Selenium. I am doing by following but not working.

```
WebElement click = driver.findElement(By.id("pd-vote-button10359300"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", click);
```

Can you Please Suggest what is the Issue ?

After

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='css-vote-button pds-vote-button' and starts-with(@id, 'pd-vote-button')]/span[text()='Vote']"))).click();
```

I got Following Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (122, 877). Other element would receive the click: <div class="nc_wrapper swp_floating_horizontal_wrapper bottom" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">...</div>
 (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'Sanjeevans-iMac.local', ip: '169.254.10.5', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '13'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.90, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4..., userDataDir: /var/folders/k2/8cltlrwj23n...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59693}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 02cb57fb86be956e5e10be634b5724b1

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)

    at bigboss.A.main(A.java:49)
```

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting?

Comment: No errors getting.But not Clickable

Comment: I read "automating spam"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.css-vote-button.pds-vote-button[id^='pd-vote-button']>span"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='css-vote-button pds-vote-button' and starts-with(@id, 'pd-vote-button')]/span[text()='Vote']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can use the `executeScript()` method as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.css-vote-button.pds-vote-button[id^='pd-vote-button']>span"))));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='css-vote-button pds-vote-button' and starts-with(@id, 'pd-vote-button')]/span[text()='Vote']"))));
  ```

**Note**: As you are using `java.version: '13'` it is worth to mention that there are some compatibility issues between [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) / [java-12](/questions/tagged/java-12) and you can find the detailed discussions in:

- [Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228)
- [Error occurred during initialization of boot layer when executing Selenium tests using TestNG and Java 12 through Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-boot-layer-when-executing-selenium-tests/57670720#57670720)

---

### tl;dr

- [Can't compile Java9 module with selenium-java as dependency](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5896)
- [Remove the WebDriverWaiter and just use a sleep for now](https://github.com/mhomnag/selenium-java10-reproducer/commit/72f3be2642f2aac82dc3c8ac9398b0d99f07858e)
- [Launch with java 11 fails: Error: Could not find or load main class with Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: with](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543562)

Comment: @Ruban4Axis Update the question with the error stacktrace please

Comment: Updated Bro Check

Comment: @Ruban4Axis Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an `ElementClickInterceptedException` error, which means some other element on the page is overlapping the element you are trying to click. You will either need to interact with the page some how so the overlapping element no longer overlaps, or use JavaScript to both click on the element and trigger a "click" event.

Many web sites have page navigation elements that scroll along with the user, so something like a floating nav header might be obstructing the element you want to click on. DebanjanB has a good solution as a next step in troubleshooting this problem, but I suspect you will get a TimeoutException while waiting for the element to be clickable.

You will most likely need to watch this automated test execute and then play with the page after the test fails before you discover how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the following to click?

```
WebElement click = driver.findElement(By.id("pd-vote-button10359300"));
click.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible your ID is getting change.Try below xpath.

```
//a[@class='css-vote-button pds-vote-button']/span[text()='Vote']
```

Code:

```
WebElement click = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='css-vote-button pds-vote-button']/span[text()='Vote']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", click);
```