# getting Module format not recognized error in eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written a selenium script,while creating project it is asking for create module if i don't create this module, directly create project run the script means will get this error."Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module format not recognized: E:\selenuim\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe
//This is my script//

```
public class LoginDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver  driver =new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     //Login to an application
    driver.get("http://aesportal.azurewebsites.net/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("demo");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("demo");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Button[@type='submit'")).click();    
    }
```

}

Comment: anybody is there to help

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-boot-layer-when-executing-selenium-tests/57670720#57670720) helps you?

Comment: no ,can you please help me in some other ways

Comment: i'm using java 8 now but still i m getting the same error.