# org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Supplied function might have stalled error using titleContains() with Selenium 4.0.0-alpha-5 and Java 11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-11, webdriverwait, selenium4

Googling yielded nothing but source code on this timeout and I seem to have no visibility via logs looking at selenium source code.  I am wondering if anyone else has run into this issue with selenium

The condition we waited on was the following

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Find a doctor"));

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Supplied function might have stalled
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-5', revision: 'b3a0d621cc'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0', java.version: '11.0.6'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:221)
    at com.orderlyhealth.scraper.json.CaredashHelper.getSearchResultsFromProviderImpl(CaredashHelper.java:320)
    at com.orderlyhealth.scraper.json.CaredashHelper.getSearchResultsFromProvider(CaredashHelper.java:294)
    at com.orderlyhealth.scraper.json.CaredashHelper.runImpl(CaredashHelper.java:65)
    at com.orderlyhealth.scraper.json.CaredashHelper.run(CaredashHelper.java:57)
    at com.orderlyhealth.scraper.json.JsonController.runBatchImpl(JsonController.java:200)
    at com.orderlyhealth.scraper.json.JsonController.executeBatch(JsonController.java:134)
    at com.orderlyhealth.scraper.json.JsonController.preRunBatchImpl(JsonController.java:110)
    at com.orderlyhealth.scraper.json.JsonController.runBatch(JsonController.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.services.ControllerInvoker.invokeController(ControllerInvoker.java:30)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.services.SvcProxyForContent.invokeAndCoerce(SvcProxyForContent.java:56)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.services.SvcProxyForContent.lambda$invokeMethod$1(SvcProxyForContent.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(Unknown Source)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.services.SvcProxyForContent.invokeMethod(SvcProxyForContent.java:49)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.services.SvcProxyForContent.lambda$invoke$0(SvcProxyForContent.java:33)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.syncToAsyncException(FutureHelper.java:169)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.services.SvcProxyForContent.invoke(SvcProxyForContent.java:33)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.services.SvcProxyForContent.invoke(SvcProxyForContent.java:19)
    at com.orderlyhealth.serverutil.filters.InternalSvcValidationFilter.filter(InternalSvcValidationFilter.java:33)
    at com.orderlyhealth.serverutil.filters.InternalSvcValidationFilter.filter(InternalSvcValidationFilter.java:13)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.loader.ChainFilters$ServiceFilterProxy.invoke(ChainFilters.java:29)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.loader.ChainFilters$ServiceFilterProxy.invoke(ChainFilters.java:17)
    at org.webpieces.plugin.json.JacksonCatchAllFilter.filter(JacksonCatchAllFilter.java:44)
    at org.webpieces.plugin.json.JacksonCatchAllFilter.filter(JacksonCatchAllFilter.java:28)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.loader.ChainFilters$ServiceFilterProxy.invoke(ChainFilters.java:29)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.loader.ChainFilters$ServiceFilterProxy.invoke(ChainFilters.java:17)
    at com.orderlyhealth.serverutil.filters.JobAndBatchIdFilter.filter(JobAndBatchIdFilter.java:33)
    at com.orderlyhealth.serverutil.filters.JobAndBatchIdFilter.filter(JobAndBatchIdFilter.java:13)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.loader.ChainFilters$ServiceFilterProxy.invoke(ChainFilters.java:29)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.loader.ChainFilters$ServiceFilterProxy.invoke(ChainFilters.java:17)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routers.Endpoint.invoke(Endpoint.java:27)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routeinvoker.ServiceInvoker.invokeService(ServiceInvoker.java:83)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routeinvoker.ServiceInvoker.lambda$invokeSvc$0(ServiceInvoker.java:67)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.syncToAsyncException(FutureHelper.java:169)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.catchBlock(FutureHelper.java:104)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.catchBlockWrap(FutureHelper.java:142)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routeinvoker.ServiceInvoker.invokeSvc(ServiceInvoker.java:66)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routebldr.RequestResponseStream.lambda$openStream$1(RequestResponseStream.java:57)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routeinvoker.RequestStreamWriter2.handleCompleteRequestImpl(RequestStreamWriter2.java:86)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routeinvoker.RequestStreamWriter2.processPiece(RequestStreamWriter2.java:68)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routers.NonStreamingWebAppErrorProxy.lambda$processPiece$0(NonStreamingWebAppErrorProxy.java:41)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.syncToAsyncException(FutureHelper.java:169)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.catchBlock(FutureHelper.java:104)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.routers.NonStreamingWebAppErrorProxy.processPiece(NonStreamingWebAppErrorProxy.java:40)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.TxStreamWriter.processPiece(TxStreamWriter.java:24)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.ProxyHttpStream$ProxyWriter.processPiece(ProxyHttpStream.java:161)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.lambda$processPiece$7(Layer2Http11Handler.java:210)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(Unknown Source)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.processPiece(Layer2Http11Handler.java:210)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.lambda$null$4(Layer2Http11Handler.java:199)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.syncToAsyncException(FutureHelper.java:169)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.finallyBlock(FutureHelper.java:55)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.lambda$processData$6(Layer2Http11Handler.java:198)
    at org.webpieces.util.locking.PermitQueue.processItemFromQueue(PermitQueue.java:82)
    at org.webpieces.util.locking.PermitQueue.runRequest(PermitQueue.java:62)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.processData(Layer2Http11Handler.java:184)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.processCorrectly(Layer2Http11Handler.java:173)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.lambda$processWithBackpressure$3(Layer2Http11Handler.java:149)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(Unknown Source)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.processWithBackpressure(Layer2Http11Handler.java:149)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.initialDataImpl(Layer2Http11Handler.java:72)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer2Http11Handler.initialData(Layer2Http11Handler.java:48)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer1ServerListener.lambda$initialData$1(Layer1ServerListener.java:62)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.syncToAsyncException(FutureHelper.java:169)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.catchBlock(FutureHelper.java:104)
    at org.webpieces.util.futures.FutureHelper.catchBlockWrap(FutureHelper.java:142)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer1ServerListener.initialData(Layer1ServerListener.java:61)
    at org.webpieces.frontend2.impl.Layer1ServerListener.incomingData(Layer1ServerListener.java:51)
    at org.webpieces.asyncserver.impl.ProxyDataListener.incomingData(ProxyDataListener.java:26)
    at org.webpieces.nio.impl.threading.ThreadDataListener$DataListeneRunanble.run(ThreadDataListener.java:54)
    at org.webpieces.util.threading.SessionExecutorImpl$RunnableWithKey.run(SessionExecutorImpl.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:209)
            ... 80 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas how to fix this?  It is happens quite a bit to us.

Comment: Is the issue specifically on moving to Java-11 or just that it happened to be the version installed on your system?

Comment: Do you observe this in alpha-4 ? There are changes in implementation of until method from aplha-5. Its using 'CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(.. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/51de5363808d6ee3c5c93cc5f36f91e17aed4ceb'

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Supplied function might have stalled
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-5', revision: 'b3a0d621cc'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0', java.version: '11.0.6'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that *TimeoutException* occurred while waiting for *title* to contain the string `Find a doctor`.

---

### Analysis

I don't see any major change in the defination of the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) [`titleContains()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L80) which is defined as follows:

```
/**
 * An expectation for checking that the title contains a case-sensitive substring
 *
 * @param title the fragment of title expected
 * @return true when the title matches, false otherwise
 */
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> titleContains(final String title) {
  return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    private String currentTitle = "";

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
      currentTitle = driver.getTitle();
      return currentTitle != null && currentTitle.contains(title);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("title to contain \"%s\". Current title: \"%s\"", title, currentTitle);
    }
  };
}
```

However the *TimeoutException* seems to be arising from [ExecutionException](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java#L209) which looks a bit odd.

```
/**
 * Repeatedly applies this instance's input value to the given function until one of the following
 * occurs:
 * <ol>
 * <li>the function returns neither null nor false</li>
 * <li>the function throws an unignored exception</li>
 * <li>the timeout expires</li>
 * <li>the current thread is interrupted</li>
 * </ol>
 *
 * @param isTrue the parameter to pass to the {@link ExpectedCondition}
 * @param <V>    The function's expected return type.
 * @return The function's return value if the function returned something different
 * from null or false before the timeout expired.
 * @throws TimeoutException If the timeout expires.
 */
@Override
public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue) {
  try {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(checkConditionInLoop(isTrue))
        .get(deriveSafeTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  } catch (ExecutionException cause) {
    if (cause.getCause() instanceof RuntimeException) {
      throw (RuntimeException) cause.getCause();
    } else if (cause.getCause() instanceof Error) {
      throw (Error) cause.getCause();
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(cause);
  } catch (InterruptedException cause) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    throw new RuntimeException(cause);
  } catch (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException cause) {
    throw new TimeoutException("Supplied function might have stalled", cause);
  }
}
```

But `driver.version: unknown` gives us a hint that there is a incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using.

Additionally, in the next release of Selenium, the constructor of [WebDriverWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java#L46) of [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) would be deprecated.

```
@Deprecated
public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds) {
  this(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
}
```

The new constructor of [WebDriverWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java#L60) to be used in [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) (currently in *Alpha*) is:

```
public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Duration timeout) {
  this(
      driver,
      timeout,
      Duration.ofMillis(DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT),
      Clock.systemDefaultZone(),
      Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER);
}
```

The usage should be:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

---

### Java 11

As you are using **java.version: '11.0.6'**, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is still not compatible with **Java 11**. But once **Java 11** ships and **Buck** supports it the toolchain witll be rejiged to support *Java 11*.

---

### Solution

The strategic solution will be to install the latest version of [**JDK 8u251**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and execute the *@Tests*

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228)

Comment: I am also seeing this same ERROR with Java 1.8.0_221 `ERROR 2021-09-13 14:21:18,600 [TestNG-tests-1] com.cubic.accelerators.WebDriverActions  - org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Supplied function might have stalled
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-6', revision: '5f43a29cfc'
System info: host: 'WL200836', ip: '10.63.10.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:221)`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when you have a bad proxy in the middle, I noticed the browsers would WAIT on the page.  This then would cause selenium drivers to hang.  It was a very intermittent issue so hard to narrow down to a proxy issue.

Comment: I had similar experience

Answer (score 0):

it is saying clearly i.e TimeoutException, change the timeout ,you given 30 ms but actually need more than that...give it as more than 30 , it will work smoothly.