# Unable to run Selenium test with Chromedriver on Mac

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Whenever I am trying to run my Java-Selenium tests locally on Mac through Chromedriver, its not invoking the browser and is getting this error as below. I am getting back to this code in couple of months time and last time could run without any issues, and in the meantime my project has not gone through any code change.

Error received as below:

> Step failed org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session
> not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version
> 80 Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
> '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: '192-168-1-115.tpgi.com.au',
> ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:105e:e823:7e44:3a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
> 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.5', java.version: '11.0.6'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver remote stacktrace: 0
> chromedriver  0x00000001030f8329 chromedriver + 3838761
>
> 1   chromedriver                        0x0000000103092123
> chromedriver + 3420451 2   chromedriver
> 0x0000000102e0662f chromedriver + 751151 3   chromedriver
> 0x0000000102d67fa6 chromedriver + 102310 4   chromedriver
> 0x0000000102d63f7f chromedriver + 85887

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228) help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't installed the correct version of Chromedriver.

Press the three dots on the right top, go to About Chrome/Chromium and check the version in light gray. And download the driver for that version.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your chrome driver exe accourding to your browser version
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/  you can download latest driver exe from this link.